# Using React :"react": "^18.2.0", "react-dom": "^18.2.0", Any idea will be greatly appreciated.. This my first tutorial in React. Thanks

Tags: reactjs

I am going through a tutorial, but getting just this error: Uncaught (in promise)
SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
Here is the simple script :

```
import React from 'react';
import{useEffect} from 'react';
const API_URL = "https://www.omdbapi.com/?i=tt3896198&apikey=ed530378";


const App = () => {
  const searchMovies = async (title)=>{
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-template-curly-in-string
        const response = await fetch('${API_URL}& s=${title}');
const data = await response.json();

console.log('data', data);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    searchMovies('superman');
  }, []);

 return (
<h1>App For David</h1>

 );
}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here
fetch('${API_URL}& s=${title}'
you're using single quotation but you need to use backticks ``
And also it's better to pass in the other parameters like method: 'Get' , headers: '' etc in the fetch call...read about the fetch api here or you can copy the code directly and make required changes : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch